# Authentication role

Tags: java, spring, testing, spring-security, mockito

I test my Controller with Mockito.
test my method in controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/dispatcher")
    public String disp(final HttpServletRequest request) {
        if (request.isUserInRole("USER")) {
            return "hello";
        } else if (request.isUserInRole("ADMIN")) {
            return "redirect:listUsers.htm";
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("This role is not registrated");
    }
```

My test method:

```
@Test

    public void testDispatcher() throws Exception {
    User user = userDao.findByLogin("log1");
    TestingAuthenticationToken testingAuthenticationToken = new TestingAuthenticationToken(user, AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("USER"));  
              SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(testingAuthenticationToken);
                System.out.println(testingAuthenticationToken);
                mockMvc.perform(post("/dispatcher")
                        .principal(testingAuthenticationToken))
                        .andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

Error:
org.springframework.security.authentication.TestingAuthenticationToken@bf72b5bd: Principal: User [id=1, firstName=name1, lastName=surname1, login=log1, email=email1@gmail.com, password=psw1, birthDate=1980-01-01 00:00:00.0, role=[id=1, name=USER]]; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: false; Details: null; Not granted any authorities

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: This role is not registrated

How i can set Role for method request.isUserInRole(); 
or maybe has another solution to my issue

Answer (score 0):

change my Test with add GrandAuthorities , but isUserinRole also "false"

```
 @Test
        public void testDispatcher() throws Exception {
            User user = userDao.findByLogin("log1");
            String sRole = user.getRole().getName();
            List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(sRole));
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken userDetails =
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getLogin(), user.getPassword(),authorities);
            TestingAuthenticationToken testingAuthenticationToken = new TestingAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null,authorities);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(testingAuthenticationToken);
            mockMvc.perform(post("/dispatcher")
                    .principal(testingAuthenticationToken))
                    .andExpect(status().isOk());
        }
```